# What is the relation between $v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4,v_5$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $x,y$ be two co prime positive integers. By Bezout theorem, there exist integers $v_1,v_2 $, such that : $$v_1\cdot x+v_2\cdot y=1$$

Assuming further that there exist integers $v_3,v_4,v_5$ such that :
$$(v_3+v_4)\cdot x+v_4\cdot y=1$$
$$v_5\cdot x+(v_4+v_5)\cdot y=1$$

My **question** is: What is the relation between $v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4,v_5 \, ? $

Comment: I added the "slope" based characterization that you may be seeking - which is not apparent in the other answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in Wikipedia's [Bézout's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity) article, when you have a specific solution $v_1$, $v_2$ such that

$$v_1\cdot x+v_2\cdot y=1 \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

then since you must have $\gcd(x,y) = 1$, the general solution would be $v_1^{'}$ and $v_2^{'}$, for an arbitrary integer $k$, of

$$v_1^{'} = v_1 + ky, \; v_2^{'} = v_2 - kx \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

Thus, comparing this to your other $2$ specific solutions of

$$(v_3+v_4)\cdot x+v_4\cdot y=1 \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

$$v_5\cdot x+(v_4+v_5)\cdot y=1 \tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$

you get that for some integers $k_1$ and $k_2$,

$$v_1 + k_1 y = v_3 + v_4, \; v_2 - k_1 x = v_4 \tag{5}\label{eq5A}$$

$$v_1 + k_2 y = v_5, \; v_2 - k_2 x = v_4 + v_5 \tag{6}\label{eq6A}$$

If you wish, you can manipulate these equations to get other relations among the various values.

Answer (score 0):

If $\,v_1 x + v_2 y = 1\,$ then  $\,\bar v_1 x + \bar v_2 y = 1$ $\overset{\rm subtract}\iff (\bar v_1\! -\!  v_1)x + (\bar v_2\! -\!v_2)y = 0\!$ $ \iff\! {-}\dfrac{y}x = \dfrac{\bar v_1 -v_1}{\bar v_2 - v_2}$

So your last two are solutions $\iff \dfrac{v_3+v_4-v_1}{v_4-v_2} = -\dfrac{y}x = \dfrac{v_5-v_1}{v_4+v_5-v_2}$

(The degenerate cases when the denominators vanish are left to the reader).